# postgresql login with react js

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express, authentication, axios

So i recently made it possible to make input to the postgressql database, but when i try to login my express console says that the data that was send is unidentified.

Here is my server on port 5000:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db")

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());

//Create account with the credentials from the signup page, and save it in postgresql database
app.post("/create", async(req,res) => {
    try {
        const results = await pool.query("INSERT INTO accounts (username, password) VALUES ($1, $2) returning *",
        [req.body.username, req.body.password]);
        console.log(results);
        console.log(req.body.username)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        console.log(req.body.username)
    }
})

app.get("/loginExpress", async(res,req) =>{
    try{
        const results = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '$1' AND password = '$2' returning *",
        [req.body.username, req.body.password])
        console.log("User found!");
    }catch(err){
        console.error(err.message)
    }
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server has started.. listening on port 5000!");
})
```

I have tried to use postman and etc. But it seems that it cant make a connection to the "http://localhost:5000/loginExpress"

Here is the React js page where i want to send the data to /loginExpress from:

```
const Login = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            const response = await Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/loginExpress", {
                username,
                password
            })
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className={classes.title}>Login</h1>
            <Box className={classes.box}>
                <form action="/loginExpress" method="POST" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
                <TextField onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} value={username} className={classes.input} id="standard-basic" label="Username" variant="standard" /><br />
                <TextField onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} value={password} className={classes.input} id="standard-basic" type="password" label="Password" variant="standard" /><br />
                <Button value="submit" type="submit" onClick={() => onSubmitForm} className={classes.button} variant="outlined" endIcon={<LoginIcon />}>
                    Login
                </Button><br />
                </form>
                <Typography>Don't have an user yet? Signup <Typography component={Link} to="/signup">here!</Typography> </Typography>
            </Box>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: I now get this as response "[ { id: 8, username: 'AnotherGuy', password: 'Password123' } ]"
But when i try to get username by console.log(results.rows.username) it says undefined